# Swift 5 Mac App - Screen Shot, copy selected area to clipboard

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to program automatic "copy selected to clipboard" (cmd-shift-ctrl+4 method) for given coords. Even tho I'm able to send event of each key, it doesn't work at all or SOMETIMES works (usually it works like second key event clear first 'down' event).

Sometimes i can make it work adding

```
usleep(useconds_t(50000))
```

But i need solution to work 100% times not at 'random'. What i'm doing wrong?

```
    func SelectRectangleToClipboard(cursorLocation startPosition: CGPoint, cursorLocation endPosition: CGPoint){
        // Enable cropped screenshot
        let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)
        let loc = CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap

        // Ctrl key down
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x3B, keyDown: true)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Command key down
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x37, keyDown: true)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Shift key down
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: true)?.post(tap: loc)

        // "4" key click (down & up)
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x15, keyDown: true)?.post(tap: loc)
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x15, keyDown: false)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Shift key up
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x38, keyDown: false)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Command key up
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x37, keyDown: false)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Ctrl key up
        CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: 0x3B, keyDown: false)?.post(tap: loc)

        // Select start
        CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown,    mouseCursorPosition: startPosition, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

        // Select move
        CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDragged,    mouseCursorPosition: endPosition, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

        // Select end
        CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp,    mouseCursorPosition: endPosition, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    }
```

Example:

```
SelectRectangleToClipboard(cursorLocation: CGPoint(x: 360, y: 416), cursorLocation: CGPoint(x: 430, y: 435))
```

Comment: If you want to capture a section of the screen you should use one of the frameworks that allow for that instead of faking keypresses to use the user's screenshot tool. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturescreeninput

Answer (score 0):

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.general()
pasteBoard.clearContents()
pasteBoard.writeObjects([text as NSString])
```

clearContents is required on macOS, otherwise the setString fails and returns FALSE.
Hope That helps? Or what kind of rectangle you want to put to clipboard, I don't get it.. sorry